# update session variable using javascript

Tags: jquery

I am creating the table with the session data. So if I am using any ajax call,How can I assign the new session data to the table. In the request it contains the session data along with other session as well as result.

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>S.no</th>
         <th>Leave Type</th>
         <th>Eligible Leaves</th>
         <th>Available Leaves</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${empty empLeaveTypeSummary}">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="4">No Data to display</td>
            </tr>
         </c:when>
         <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach var="lst" items="${empLeaveTypeSummary}"varStatus="loop">
               <tr id="tsRow${loop.index + 1}">
                  <td>
                     <c:out value="${loop.index + 1}" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <c:out value="${lst.leaveTypeName}" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <c:out value="${lst.leaveEligibility}" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <c:out value="${lst.leaveBalance}" />
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </c:forEach>
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way to refresh the table/session variable

Comment: You leaving out a lot here. This is some kind of PHP template, please incude your JS.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side so it wont be possible to change a value of server side object,
although You can use ajax call to call a server side

`web method` to do this work for you

Answer (score 0):

As you might know JSP is compiled to java then to class file and then to create the html file.

So even if you update the session with the updated value through ajax without reloading the page data won't be reflected in the table.

I suggest you use jQuery [Data Table](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin to load the data from server through ajax.